# Creating Right to Left user interface for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

As per apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH17-SW1)
"iOS doesn’t automatically mirror controls, so if you want this behaviour for an iOS app, subclass the control and override the drawing methods."

I want to mirror my whole UI when the user selects the language as Arabic or hebrew in the home screen. i was searching for tutorials and documentation for the same but nothing helps.

Please find what i have done till now:
am using Xcode 6.1 and the app targets from iOS 7 to iOS 8.1. 
Autolayout is enabled and am not using left or right constraints. am using only leading or trailing constraints.
Base internationalisation is enabled in project settings also have added the languages in localization. but when am running the app in device and set device language and region to arabic i cant get the mirrored UI. Do i have to do anything in code to get the mirrored UI?
What is the best way to support RTL based UI? How to subclass control and override drawing methods?

Please use [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycar93s6j8djv33/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-22%20at%2012.51.44%20AM.png?dl=0) to get the sample screenshot of my app.

Comment: Why don't you try with two different views in storyboard, with the same IBOutlet attached? Place the scene whichever you required dependent over language.

Comment: Am just keeping that as last option because i have nearly 43 screens and also for iPhone 6 plus am planning to have different storyboard. Am just wondering why apple doesnt have clear documentation for this when os x apps can mirror without any efforts :(

Comment: In that case, you require to manage all the Constraints through codebase.

Comment: @Mrunal Do you mean that i have to manage all the constraints in code and when user selects arabic, i have to changes the constraints so that i can get the mirrored UI?

Comment: Yes, if I change left constraint from 10 to 250 my uilabel will move to right aligned. But this is very hactic and not so good solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer anyway. I have lots of custom controls also i guess for RTL UI support there is no easy way :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65520/discussion-between-mrunal-and-bluewings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a easy way from Apple documentations instead of having 2 storyboards for RTL and LTR languages.

1. First of all enable Base internationalisation in project settings
2. Add your language - in my case i have added arabic and hebrew
3. xCode will localize your stroy boards and you can see different storyboard strings for different languages
4. Change the texts for your labels in the newly created strings file. In my case i changed in arabic and hebrew string files
5. Use AutoLayout for designing the whole UI.
6. Don't use Left or right constraints. Instead of use only leading and trailing constraints
7. Add the below code in your main function and run the app in simulator

> ```
> NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil]; 
> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
> ```

Your app now will work for RTL language with mirrored UI without having 2 storyboards.
Note : if you are not setting the autolayout constraints correctly it wont work. However because of the new screens you have to learn to use auto layout.

Comment: @Jitendra what was the problem? explain in details please

Comment: I want to shift all UI to left side

Comment: all the UI is not possible with the above answer. it can only shift labels and texts. For UI Controls you have to customise and re draw the controls. For example if you want UISegmentedControl To switch RTL you have to customise the controls. check out the link in my question.

Comment: I want to change the language from my app.(Not whole device language)
For that according to language selection I have set the language code value in "AppleLanguages" NSUserDefaults.
But how can I refresh the UI?

Comment: @VivekShah you have to force reload the window root view controller for that.

Comment: But it needs restarting app by user.

Comment: @Bluewings I am not able to refresh the view after changing the language from the app. I have tried to set window root. but it run While I am doing the language change from phone setting

Comment: @Bluewings is it possible without Autolayout ? because my app is almost complete without autolayout.

Comment: @NiravKotecha as far as I know it won't work without auto layout. Since we have many size classes. You should probably update the app to use auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

in Swift

```
let languages = ["ar"]
UserDefaults.standard.set(languages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```

Comment: This answer could probably benefit from a little extra context/explanation as to why this solution works.